# Do tokens waiting to be unstaked still function as staked tokens?

Tags: staking

If I unstake 1000 EOS tokens, for example, do they still work as staked tokens during the 3-day waiting period? i.e. will bp votes I have cast still count until the exact moment they are unstaked?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since no one answered, I tried it myself. After unstaking I checked bloks.io and the tokens have moved from "staked" to "refunding" so I guess the answer is no, they no longer function as staked tokens once you begin the unstaking process.